# How to setup multiple websites on one NGINX with Vagrant?

Tags: networking, nginx, vagrant

I have virtual ubuntu-server managed by Vagrant. I've installed NGINX and created 3 virtual servers. They all have names: test1.localhost, test2.localhost, test3.localhost. When I try to browse my test websites everything is fine but only when I open them inside my virtual machine (lynx test1.localhost, lynx ..., etc).

Why I can't view my websites on host machine? Why, when I type `test1.localhost:8080` or `test2.localhost:8080` or `test3.localhost:8080`, I get error "Server Not Found?".

- When I type `127.0.0.1:8080` I see test1.localhost website.

***Edit***

- I just discovered that my configuration is working properly on chromium browser and Google Chrome! Why firefox is unable to show `test1.localhost:8080`, `test2.localhost:8080`, `test3.localhost:8080` and chromium-browser can?
- OK, I found it, it's problem with firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1433933

***test1.conf***

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/test1;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name test1.localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

***test2.conf***

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        root /var/www/test2;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name test2.localhost;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

***test3.conf***

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/test3;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name test3.localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

***/etc/hosts***

```
127.0.0.1       localhost test1.localhost test2.localhost test3.localhost
127.0.1.1       vagrant

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

***Vagrantfile***

```
...
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" # nginx
...
```

Comment: Is your host OS configured to use the /etc/hosts file?  Check /etc/nsswitch.conf  hosts: line.

Answer (score 0):

The http works this way that when typing http://example.com:8080/abc?def into the browser bar, behind the scenes url is cut into four parts:

1. `http:`
2. `example.com`
3. `8080`
4. `/abc?def`

And roughly speaking this is how the parts 1 2 3 4 are used:

```
$ telnet  2  3
(no TLS negotiation here, because 1)
GET 4    HTTP/1.1
Host: 2:3      <---- look here
User-agent: blah-blah
Accept: blah blah

----------------------
```

So nginx knows that you want `test1.localhost:8080` and not `test1.localhost:80`. Don't change a http port on TCP layer. You need to use a `proxy_pass` to do this.